# Does the low rep comment barrier decrease quality of the comments?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

I don't understand why the rep requirement for comments on meta is this low.
In my opinion 25 would improve quality of comments.

But has the low rep requirement actually made the comments that much worse?

Comment: This is a low quality comment.

Comment: What specific problem(s) do you think is caused by the barrier being where it is, and how do you think things would be improved if it were higher? "Low quality" is rather vague and likely means many different things to many different people.

Comment: I think @Glorfindel, who just commented on this question make perfect example.  please do not remove.

Comment: @RyadShaanbi thanks, but how often do you actually see this? And how often is it done by <25 rep users?

Comment: I feel like 15-20 rep range would already improve comments but in my experience comments from commenters with under 100 rep are lower quality than those of 500+ .

Comment: @Glorfindel I asked this question because I was surprised to see the required 5 rep instead of 50 we see normally on other SEs, I haven't seen comments like those yet but I'm sure they are more common here than other SEs.

Comment: @RyadShaanbi I can understand the surprise (I didn't know it myself until this morning) but I hope I have explained why it is so low. And my *opinion* is that raising the required reputation solves a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Glorfindel Does raising the required rep harm the community? 
because when it doesn't affect the comments quality , is it better to keep it where its at or experiment?

Comment: Yes, I *think* it will hinder some people from participating in a valuable way in a Meta discussion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We need to have a reputation barrier for comments; comments don't bump questions like answers do, so they are harder to moderate. If you could comment with 1 reputation already, this would open an avenue for spammers / rude and abusive comments (e.g. creating a new account just to jerk at another user).

On the other hand, Meta is a place where we *discuss* matters. It's very hard to have a discussion with questions and answers only. Therefore, I believe the current threshold of [5 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) makes perfect sense. If you do see low-quality comments, you can always [flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) them (well, you need 15 reputation of course).

> But has the low rep requirement actually made the comments that much worse?

IMHO we do not have a comment problem on Meta. At least not a bigger problem than on main sites. However, we can't see deleted (low quality) comments, so a Stack Exchange employee has to confirm.

Comment: You didn't answer the question "But has the low rep requirement actually made the comments that much worse?"

Comment: We could flag them, however the sheer amount of flags one would require to make to clean even 10% of the low quality comments O.o

Comment: @PatrickHofman IIRC, it read differently when the question was posted. As it stands, it's hard to tell and maybe even too opinion-based to answer. Maybe an SE employee has some statistics on this matter. The main problem is that we (normal users) can't see deleted comments.

Comment: 5 reputation did not take my long to take less than a day in this case.
Therefore i think it is too low.