# User page, "all-actions" tab, "comments" sub-tab... add a "delete" option

Tags: feature-request, comments

It seems as though [the community believes that comments are mostly temporary and easily outlive their usefulness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325250/should-all-comments-be-deleted).  Although [there does not seem to be evidence that "no longer relevant" comments are a site-wide problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325395/are-too-many-comments-irrelevant), it would be nice to have the option to easily clean up my own old, "no longer relevant" comments.  An answerer from the first link above seems to agree: "Ideally folks clean up their own comments after themselves."

One way to streamline this would be to put a "delete" button, e.g. here:

[image: comment page delete button]

As it stands, going to visit all of the pages on which I have previously commented to delete it is quite time-consuming.  I would like to be a responsible comment-leaver.  It seems that that responsibility includes cleaning up my comments, and I am willing and eager to do that thing, so long as there is an efficient means to do so.

Comment: We do want to keep comments trimmed but you shouldn't *just* be deleting comments, you should be deleting them when they no longer serve a purpose - for example, the post was edited. So... my big/first concern is people deleting comments without considering or even checking for context. Yes, you can do that on the post, too. But it's much easier to see if you're going to break a comment chain when you're on the post than completely out of context on a list of comments.

Comment: @Catija it might need some more design effort but I do like the idea that you moderate your own comments from there. Maybe add an count to indicate how many more comments are present on the post, or how many other users have left comments, or if the post was updated after the comment was left. I give you the idea is a bit rough on the edges but I think it has some merit and shouldn't get  a negative reception upfront from the CM team. Certainly worth an experiment with an userscript to see how it goes.

Comment: @rene Sure. At this point, with the work being done on the profiles, I can't even say if this tab will even exist any more... or what it will look like if it does. But a count wouldn't be enough. It'd have to be an in-page preview of some sort, like what's on the revisions tab.

Comment: @Catija "to see if you're going to break a comment chain" If my comment is obsolete, then surely the entire chain is.  Do you think, therefore, that breaking the chain might be a *good thing* because it removes the illusion that the comments were relevant to begin with?  To clarify, a group of comments may be cohesive as a whole, but still be irrelevant to the post to which they are connected.

Comment: Actually, no. Cody takes my explanation a bit further, so if you read his answer you'll see the problem with this... you break the chain and it makes things confusing. If you're on the post itself, you can flag the other obsolete comments and they can all be removed. Without that context, you're leaving people confused because they can't even see that your comment existed at some point in the past. There may be some value in a middle ground as I've mentioned in my previous comment but just a delete button with no context is likely to make things worse.

Comment: "you can flag the other obsolete comments and they can all be removed."  The first link in the question contains a number of citations where people are upset that their comments have been deleted.  I absolutely do not flag comments unless they are really very bad.  I am 100x more likely and willing to clean up my own comments and although I think that "comment cleanliness" might be a worthy goal, I definitely believe that "comment clean-up" by the moderator team is the wrong way to achieve that goal.

Comment: With this in mind, and taking your concerns also into consideration, there is an unfortunate situation where comment threads become self-sustaining whether or not they are relevant to the post.... Is it possible to reconcile these ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good idea, for the reasons [Catija posted in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/325721/user-page-all-actions-tab-comments-sub-tab-add-a-delete-option#comment1063397_325721):

> We do want to keep comments trimmed but you shouldn't *just* be deleting comments, you should be deleting them when they no longer serve a purpose - for example, the post was edited.

The problem with a change like this is that **it would encourage people to delete comments independent of context, which makes the resulting discussion *extremely* confusing and difficult to follow**:

> …my big/first concern is people deleting comments without considering or even checking for context. Yes, you can do that on the post, too. But it's much easier to see if you're going to break a comment chain when you're on the post than completely out of context on a list of comments.

When you visit the post, you can see all of the comments in context, and there's a handy "delete" link to clean up your comments. There's also a handy "flag" link to get other obsolete comments deleted.

Yes, this is a bit more work than just blindly deleting everything. Content curation tends to be a bit more work than the shotgun approach. It's also much more effective in the long term. If you don't want to spend time cleaning up your comments, then you don't have to. If you're going to do so, please do so in a way that leaves the site *better*.